# How to augment a class from an external library with own methods?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, monkeypatching

I have some special cases that I need to test for in django. I am trying to extend the the existing django tests by writing my own test cases. Here is how I am currently doing it.

```
from django.tests import TestCase

# define my own method as a function
def assertOptionsEqual(self, first, second):
    # logic here
    pass

# Attach the method to the TestCase class. This feels inelegant!
TestCase.assertOptionsEqual = assertOptionsEqual

# tests go here
class KnownGoodInputs(TestCase):
    def test_good_options(self):
        self.assertOptionsEqual(...)
```

While this works, defining a method as a function with `self` as the first parameter and then attaching it to `TestCase` feels inelegant. Is there a better way of augmenting the `TestCase` class with my own methods? I can do this ...

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def assertOptionsEqual(self, first, second):
        ...
```

and use `MyTestCase` for all tests, but was wondering if there was a better alternative. Thanks!

Comment: What about just subclassing and use another method name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've covered both options.  You can either subclass or monkeypatch.  Typically, monkeypatching, actually changing the 3rd party class at runtime is frowned upon but depending on what change you need to make it may be the only way to work around a bug or make sure that every time that class is used it has your new method.

Since the only tests that use your method will be *your* tests monkeypatching is unnecessary and it's quite reasonable to subclass `TestCase`.  Typically you'd use monkeypatching when you needed to augment a method of a existing class.  For example, if you wanted calls to `TestCase.assertEqual` in your existing test cases to be augmented with logic to compare to `Option` objects you could monkeypatch `TestCase.assertEqual` to include your custom logic plus its normal logic by doing something like:

```
originalAssertEqual = TestCase.assertEqual
def newAssertEqual(self, first, second):
    result = originalAssertEqual(first, second)
    if isinstance(first, Option) and isinstance(second, Option):
        # do your custom comparison
    return result
TestCase.assertEqual = newAssertEqual
```

However, it seems that at least in this example that both subclasses and monkeypatches are unnecessary.

Assuming that the issue is that calling `self.assertEqual(firstOptions, secondOptions)` fails even though the `Option` instances are equal you don't need to write a new `assertOptionsEqual` method.  You probably just need your `Option` objects to define `__eq__` properly.

So assuming that you've got:

```
class KnownGoodInputs(TestCase):
    def test_good_options(self):
        first, second = systemUnderTestGetOptions(...)
        self.assertOptionsEqual(first, second)
```

What are the classes of `first` and `second` above?

For all Python builtin types `assertEqual` should work.  For a custom `Option` class just do something like this:

class Option(object):
    def **init**(self):
        use_foo = False
        use_bar = True

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if (self.use_foo == other.use_foo and
        self.use_bar == other.use_bar):
        return True
    return False
```

Then assuming that `first` and `second` are instances of `Option` you can write your test just as:

```
class KnownGoodInputs(TestCase):
    def test_good_options(self):
        first, second = systemUnderTestGetOptions(...)
        self.assertEqual(first, second)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Trying to define `__eq__` was the first choice. However, the objects being compared were Django native objects (Aggregates, QuerySets etc.) which do not have the `__eq__` defined. So I was either going to have to monkeypatch an `__eq__` method for some native Django objects or monkeypatch the TestCases. So I guess I was trying to choose the lesser of the two evils! ;)